# How to put export class of component in angular material

Tags: angular-material, angular6

Hello i want to insert a select dropdownlist with angular material.

My question is where we put this exactly :

```js
export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
}
```

[Link of the component](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

I did this :

**app.module .ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { InterfaceComponent } from './interface/interface.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InterfaceComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
 MatTabsModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatInputModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And i added html code in **app.component.html**

**Result :**

select list but without options cause i didn't know where i will put the export details

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw6Pp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this case you have to put in the app.component.ts like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
}
```